# Python Pandas Panel counting value occurence

Tags: python, pandas, panel

I have a large dataset stored as a pandas panel. I would like to count the occurence of values < 1.0 on the minor_axis for each item in the panel. What I have so far:

```
    #%% Creating the first Dataframe
    dates1 = pd.date_range('2014-10-19','2014-10-20',freq='H')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(index = dates)
    n1 = len(dates)

    df1.loc[:,'a'] = np.random.uniform(3,10,n1)
    df1.loc[:,'b'] = np.random.uniform(0.9,1.2,n1)

    #%% Creating the second DataFrame
    dates2 = pd.date_range('2014-10-18','2014-10-20',freq='H')
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = dates2)
    n2 = len(dates2)

    df2.loc[:,'a'] = np.random.uniform(3,10,n2)
    df2.loc[:,'b'] = np.random.uniform(0.9,1.2,n2)

    #%% Creating the panel from both DataFrames
    dictionary = {}
    dictionary['First_dataset'] = df1
    dictionary['Second dataset'] = df2

    P = pd.Panel.from_dict(dictionary)

    #%% I want to count the number of values < 1.0 for all datasets in the panel
    ## Only for minor axis b, not minor axis a, stored seperately for each dataset
    for dataset in P:
        P.loc[dataset,:,'b'] #I need to count the numver of values <1.0 in this pandas_series
```

Comment: Having never dealt with panels before I tried this :`P[P.minor_axis == 'a'].min()` does it do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for thinking with me guys, but I managed to figure out a surprisingly easy solution after many hours of attempting. I thought I should share it in case someone else is looking for a similar solution.

```
    for dataset in P:
        abc = P.loc[dataset,:,'b']
        abc_low = sum(i < 1.0 for i in abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

To count all the "b" values < 1.0, I would first isolate b in its own DataFrame by swapping the minor axis and the items.

```
In [43]: b = P.swapaxes("minor","items").b

In [44]: b.where(b<1.0).stack().count()
Out[44]: 30
```